# Click on images in adaptive card is not triggering action on IOS devices

Tags: ios, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Click on images in the adaptive card is not triggering action on IOS devices despite its opening the image viewer.

click is working expected on the web app, desktop app, and Android devices
but failing on ios devices.

[adaptive card with the clickable image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjK9X.jpg)

[after clicking its opening like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ndt1.jpg)

Card Json:

```
{
  'contentType': 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
  'content': {
    'type': 'AdaptiveCard',
    'version': '1.2',
    'body': [
      {
        'type': 'TextBlock',
        'size': 'medium',
        'weight': 'Bolder',
        'text': 'Here is the list of top analysis created for you: '
      },
      {
        'type': 'ColumnSet',
        'columns': [
          {
            'type': 'Column',
            'spacing': 'medium',
            'items': [
              {
                'type': 'Container',
                'items': [
                  {
                    'type': 'Image',
                    'url': {image_url},
                    'horizontalAlignment': 'Center',
                    'width': '96px',
                    'height': '96px'
                  }
                ],
                'selectAction': {
                  'type': 'Action.Submit',
                  'tooltip': 'Submit action',
                  'data': {
                    'bot_id': 113
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                'type': 'ColumnSet',
                'verticalAlignment': 'Center',
                'columns': [
                  {
                    'type': 'Column',
                    'items': [
                      {
                        'type': 'TextBlock',
                        'text': 'Beagle Recruit',
                        'horizontalAlignment': 'Center',
                        'weight': 'bolder',
                        'wrap': True,
                        'maxLines': 2
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            'width': 'stretch',
            'horizontalAlignment': 'Center'
          }
        ],
        'horizontalAlignment': 'Center'
      },
      {
        'type': 'ColumnSet',
        'columns': [
          
        ],
        'horizontalAlignment': 'Center'
      },
      {
        'type': 'TextBlock',
        'text': 'Select more analysis from the drop-down: ',
        'spacing': 'extralarge',
        'weight': 'Bolder',
        'wrap': True
      },
      {
        'type': 'Input.ChoiceSet',
        'id': 'botid_d',
        'spacing': 'large',
        'isMultiSelect': False,
        'value': 0,
        'placeholder': 'List of analysis',
        'choices': [
          {
            'title': 'List of analysis',
            'value': 0
          },
          {
            'title': 'Beagle Recruit',
            'value': 113
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'type': 'ActionSet',
        'style': 'default',
        'spacing': 'large',
        'actions': [
          {
            'type': 'Action.Submit',
            'color': 'default',
            'title': 'Open'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    'msteams': {
      'width': 'Full'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: plz share your code and more explain.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Please share your card JSON as well if possible

Answer (score 0):

We tried with the below json and it worked for us both in teams desktop/web and mobile clients(iOS). On click of images is triggering action. Could you please refer this?

JSON:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "auto",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://demo-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/sample.png",
              "altText": "Navigation and Help",
              "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Navigation and help",
                "data": {
                  "msteams": {
                    "type": "imBack",
                    "value": "Can you help me with Navigation and Help"
                  }
                }
              },
              "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
              "width": "100px"
            }
          ],
          "height": "stretch",
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "spacing": "Padding"
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": "auto",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://demo-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/sample.png",
              "altText": " Learning and development",
              "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Learning and development",
                "data": {
                  "msteams": {
                    "type": "imBack",
                    "value": "Can you help me with Learning and development"
                  }
                }
              },
              "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
              "width": "100px"
            }
          ],
          "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
          "spacing": "Padding"
        }
      ],
      "style": "default",
      "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
      "spacing": "Padding",
      "height": "stretch"
    },
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.1"
}
```

[image]